# add camera plugin in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros2, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have added camera plugin in a .urdf file but then I could not added in a launch.py file because of that image topic not published.
Is my urdf file correct? And how can I added launch file to publish image topic?

```
<joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="link_3"/>
        <child link="camera_link"/>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.4"/>
    </joint>


<gazebo reference="camera_link">
    <sensor type="camera" name="camera1">
      <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
      <camera name="head">
        <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>800</width>
          <height>800</height>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.02</near>
          <far>300</far>
        </clip>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <!-- Noise is sampled independently per pixel on each frame.
               That pixel's noise value is added to each of its color
               channels, which at that point lie in the range [0,1]. -->
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.007</stddev>
        </noise>
      </camera>
      <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
        <cameraName>robotic_arm/camera1</cameraName>
        <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <frameName>camera_link</frameName>
        <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
        <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412944/add-camera-plugin-in-gazebo/) by [gurselturkeri](https://answers.ros.org/users/99062/gurselturkeri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2023-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2023-02-28**:
Hello @gurselturkeri,

Is it possible to share your code so I can have a look what's the issue? It can be either full code or git repo.

Thanks

**Comment by [gurselturkeri](https://answers.ros.org/users/99062/gurselturkeri/) on 2023-02-28**:
Launch file is same as in this question: https://answers.ros.org/question/412742/controller-manager-not-available-in-ros2/

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2023-02-28**:
Tick the answer if you think it is right so it can help others in the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @gurselturkeri,

> have added camera plugin in a .urdf file but then I could not added in a launch.py

If you have added camera in urdf file then you don't need to add it to your launch file.

sudo apt-get install ros-humble-gazebo-plugins

Note: You need to add camera plugins for the gazebo also as you did in your urdf.

> but then I could not added in a launch.py file because of that image topic not published. Is my urdf file correct?

I think you forgot to [add camera link](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) into your urdf which you have shared above.

```
<!-- Camera -->
  <link name="camera_link">
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
    <box size="${camera_link} ${camera_link} ${camera_link}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
    <box size="${camera_link} ${camera_link} ${camera_link}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red"/>
    </visual>

    <inertial>
      <mass value="1e-5" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
    </inertial>
  </link>

<joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_4"/>
    <child link="camera_link"/>
  </joint>
```

> And how can I added launch file to publish image topic?

It will publish frames based on the gazebo settings you are doing in your plugin on camera_controller. In your case, it will be automatically published when the gazebo start based on your code

You can check this by opening rviz2 by hitting  command in your terminal `ros2 run rviz2 rviz2`
or by `ros2 topic list`

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

As you can see above image, you can see a boll and the robot base in the rviz image visualize.

Feel free to drop an comment if you have any question,

so, my full urdf file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="robot_1">

  <link name="world"/>

    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.2"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="Black">
                <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.025"/>
        </visual>

    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.2"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.025"/>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.025"/>
        <mass value="5.0"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.0135" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0135" iyz="0.0" izz="0.05"/>
    </inertial>
    

    </link>

  <joint name="fixed" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
    <dynamics damping="10" friction="1.0"/>

  </joint>

  <link name="link_1">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.5" radius="0.08"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="blue">
            <color rgba="0 0 0.8 1"/>
          </material>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.25"/>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.5" radius="0.08"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.25"/>
    </collision>
    
    <inertial>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.25"/>
        <mass value="5.0"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.107" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.107" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0125"/>
    </inertial>

  </link>
  
  <joint name="joint_1" type="continuous">
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="link_1"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.05"/>
    <dynamics damping="10" friction="1.0"/>

  </joint>

<link name="link_2">
    <inertial>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.2"/>
        <mass value="2.0"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.027" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.027" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0025"/>
    </inertial>

    <visual>
        <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.08"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Red">
            <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
          </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.08"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>

</link>

<joint name="joint_2" type="continuous">
<axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
<parent link="link_1"/>
<child link="link_2"/>
<origin rpy="0 1.5708 0" xyz="0.0 -0.005 0.58"/>
<limit lower="-0.25" upper="3.34" effort="10" velocity="0.5"/>
<dynamics damping="10" friction="1.0"/>

</joint>

<link name="link_3">
    <inertial>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.2"/>
        <mass value="0.01"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.027" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.027" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0025"/>
    </inertial>
    
    <visual>
        <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.4" radius="0.05"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="blue">
            <color rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 1"/>
          </material>
        <!-- <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.2"/> -->
        </visual>

    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.4" radius="0.05"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
</link>

<joint name="joint_3" type="fixed">
<parent link="link_2"/>
<child link="link_3"/>
<origin rpy="1.57 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.2 0 "/>
<dynamics damping="10" friction="1.0"/>

</joint>

<link name="link_4">
    <inertial>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.2"/>
        <mass value="0.01"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.027" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.027" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0025"/>
    </inertial>

    <visual>
        <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.06"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Red">
            <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
          </material>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.06"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>

</link>

<joint name="joint_4" type="continuous">
<parent link="link_3"/>
<child link="link_4"/>
<origin rpy="1.57 0 0" xyz=" 0 0 -0.25"/>
<axis xyz=" 0 0 1"/>
<limit lower="-1.92" upper="1.92" effort="10" velocity="0.5"/>
<dynamics damping="10" friction="1.0"/>

</joint>




<link name="link_5">
    <inertial>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.2"/>
        <mass value="0.01"/>
        <inertia ixx="0.027" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.027" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0025"/>
    </inertial>
    
    <visual>
        <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.3" radius="0.03"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="yello">
            <color rgba="0 1 0.5 1"/>
        </material>
        </visual>

    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.3" radius="0.03"/>
        </geometry>
    <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
    
    </collision>
</link>

<joint name="joint_5" type="fixed">
<parent link="link_4"/>
<child link="link_5"/>
<origin rpy="1.57 0 0" xyz="0.0 -0.2 0 "/>
<dynamics damping="10" friction="1.0"/>

</joint>

<!-- Camera -->
  <link name="camera_link">
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
    <box size="${camera_link} ${camera_link} ${camera_link}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
    <box size="${camera_link} ${camera_link} ${camera_link}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red"/>
    </visual>

    <inertial>
      <mass value="1e-5" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
    </inertial>
  </link>



<joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_4"/>
    <child link="camera_link"/>
  </joint>






<gazebo reference="base_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_1">
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_3">
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_2">
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_4">
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="link_5">
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
</gazebo>


 <gazebo reference="camera_link">
    <sensor type="camera" name="camera1">
      <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
      <camera name="head">
        <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>800</width>
          <height>800</height>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.02</near>
          <far>300</far>
        </clip>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <!-- Noise is sampled independently per pixel on each frame.
               That pixel's noise value is added to each of its color
               channels, which at that point lie in the range [0,1]. -->
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.007</stddev>
        </noise>
      </camera>
      <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
        <cameraName>rrbot/camera1</cameraName>
        <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <frameName>camera_link</frameName>
        <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
        <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>


<gazebo>
  <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
    <robot_sim_type>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</robot_sim_type>
    <parameters>/home/airobo/ros2_ws/src/big_bazu/config/jtc.yaml</parameters>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>




<ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
    <hardware>
      <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
</hardware>


<joint name="joint_1">
    <command_interface name="position">
      <param name="min">-3.14</param>
      <param name="max">3.14</param>
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position"/>
    <param name="initial_position">0.0</param>  
  </joint>
  <joint name="joint_2">
    <command_interface name="position">
      <param name="min">-3.14</param>
      <param name="max">3.14</param>
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position"/>
    <param name="initial_position">-1.57</param>  
  </joint>
  <joint name="joint_4">
    <command_interface name="position">
      <param name="min">-3.14</param>
      <param name="max">3.14</param>
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position"/>
    <param name="initial_position">0.0</param>  
  </joint>

</ros2_control>

</robot>
```

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2023-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1